# QtAV and cleaning of the buffer

Tags: c++, qt, qbytearray, qiodevice, qbuffer

I'm writing an application in Qt that permits the video streaming from a byte array.
As video output component I'm using QtAV (http://www.qtav.org/).
In my case the input of this component is a QIODevice (QBuffer) where has a QByteArray with my data.
I will put during the streaming the data inside the QByteArray, but I don't know how to delete the data that I have yet read.
My problem is that after a little time, the dimension of QByteArray is very huge and I don't know how I can reduce the memory allocated.

Thank you

Angelo

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get a reference to a byte array object from your buffer using the method
[**`QByteArray &QBuffer::buffer()`**](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuffer.html#buffer) and then erase it:

```
your_io_buffer.buffer().resize(0);
```

But please note that frequent removal and appending data to a dynamic array will cause memory reallocations, which is not so fast operation. Therefore I recommend to use the
[**`void QByteArray::reserve(int size)`**](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#reserve) method:

```
QByteArray buf;
buf.reserve(100000);
//...
your_io_buffer.setBuffer(&buf);
//...
```

Comment: I created a new QIODevice that remove the bytes that the AvPlayer has read. The problem is that I can't remove all bytes because the AvPlayer reads 32k bytes per time. thank you very much for your answer.